# Update controller path in all class dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, directory, path, dependencies

Dears,

I have a file **EmailVerification.php** under the subdirectory:

> *App\http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController.php*

in my Laravel 8 project.

I would like to create a new sub folder under Auth Folder so that my new file path is:

> *App\http\Controllers\Auth\Email Verification\VerificationController.php*

Once created, I would like to update automatically all dependencies in all my project classes of that file without doing it manually.

Is it feasible ?

Thanks.

Looking forward to having your support.

Comment: find/replace in your IDE

Comment: You can't do it automatically, but manually. Follow the instruction as @Felippe mentioned above

Comment: I know that, I though it can be done through a command or there is another workaround. Find/Replace will take a lot of time since I am talking about many files.

Comment: It can be done with a good IDE. Eg. With PHPStorm you can right click on your class name -> refactor -> move class